# How to set scroll bar size based on number of entries in FlowLayoutPanel control?

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I am using `FlowLayoutPanel` control in which I load only 40 controls at time dynamically.
But I have more than 2000 controls to add in `FlowLayoutPanel`. We add more 40 controls on scroll event and remove previous 40 controls and so on, it's done successfully. But the problem is that size of `FlowLayoutPanel`'s `ScrollBar` is set based on that 40 controls. So user can't understand whether there is new controls or not. For these purpose I have to set `ScrollBar`'s size based on total count and load only 40 controls at time.

This is same as virtual mode in `DataGridView`. I want to do it in `FlowLayoutPanel`.